# Rails3 partial index with postgresql

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3.2, postgresql-9.1

In a migration, a partial index is defined as follows to have only column price_1 where its value is greater than zero.

```
  add_index :products, :price_1, where: "(price_1 > '0')"
```

the schema states

```
  add_index "products", ["price_1"], :name => "index_products_on_price_1"
```

and the migration states

```
-- add_index(:products, :price_1, {:where=>"(price_1 > '0')"})
```

Neither rails nor postgreSQL seem to have complained.

However I am unsure as to whether the syntax is correct across the stack... and given this index is mission critical, I'm asking 'is air tight'?

exclude NULL values is also required.  But I believe the definition covers that.

Comment: Shouldn't `"(price_1 > '0')"` be `"(price_1 > 0)"`? You are comparing numbers rather than strings, aren't you?

Comment: Yes I'm comparing numbers.  but 0 and 1 are also boolean values.  Which raises my uncertainty

Comment: but `price_1` is a number... have you run any tests to see if it works as expected?

Comment: Forgot to mention that price_1 is a decimal.  Getting expected results...  I'll try your suggestion to see what happens.

Comment: Returns the same expected results.